# How to Parse a given LALR(1) Grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, automata, lalr, lr1

I'm having trouble parsing the following grammar using the LALR method.

```
s -> y
y -> dX | ydX
X -> e | Zd
z -> F | epsilon
```

I'm ok at the beginning, here is item state 0: (the , seperates the lookahead states)

```
s -> .y, $
y -> .dX, $d
y -> .ydX, $d
```

Now this is fine, but when you move to state 1 off of a d terminal I get confused. My book has state 2 as the following:

```
y -> d.X, $d
X -> .e, $d
X -> .Zd, $d
Z -> .f, d
Z -> ., d
```

Where does the lookahead terminal "d" come from in the X non-terminal? I thought that d.X came from .dX which had the lookahead terminals "$" and $d". But when doing the E-closure shouldnt the lookaheads be the first of $d which is "$"? why is it "$", or "d"? I thought it might come from another state since this is LALR but the state I end up merging state 1 with also doesn't have a d in the lookahead. Can somebody explain to me why there is a "d" paired with the "$" in the lookahead of this state? Thanks.

Comment: `$d` here is not a two-symbol lookahead; it's shorthand for the set `{$, d}`. `FIRST` of a set consists of  all the symbols which are in `FIRST` of an element of the set, so `FIRST({$, d})` is precisely `{$, d}`.

Answer (score 0):

S$->Y$->dX$  in this derivation sequence after d what follows X is {$}

S$->Y$->ydX$->dXdX$  in this derivation after first d what follows X is {d}

both derivation sequences are covered in same state after covering first symbol in the input'd'

Comment: I'm still confused. I get that when going through the grammar what follows X is {d}, but I have always been taught that when doing the E-closure, you take the first of the string that comes after that non-terminal. Why doesn't that work in this case?

Comment: There are two cases: case1: A->aBβ we will take the FIRST(β) but if FIRST(β) contains null or A->aB then what ever that follows A should be considered.